# using image as entries in listpreference

Tags: android, listview, android-preferences, listpreference

I have used the listpreference in my preference screen. I wants to show the image in list entries. I have used the code but I am getting image address instead of image in entries. Help me with this problem.

Here is my code:

preferencecheckbox.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ListPreference
    android:key="listkey"
    android:title="select"
    android:summary="Select type"
    android:entries="@array/array"
    android:entryValues="@array/value"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

array.xml

```
<resources>
<array name="array">
    <item>@drawable/image1</item>
    <item>@drawable/image2</item>
    <item>@drawable/image3</item>
</array>
<string-array name="value">
    <item>data1</item>
    <item>data2</item>
    <item>data3</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: list preference doesnt support images it only allow strings

Comment: can I show icons with the string?

Comment: you need a write a custom preference for that

Comment: Just wondering if they added image support in the mean time